# npm ci in Jenkins parallel pipeline

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, npm-ci

I've got a monorepo with roughly the following structure (npm modules):

```
myProject
|-base
|-ui1
|-ui2
```

In the `base` module I have all the stuff combined which my `ui1` and `ui2` projects use commonly. I use npm local paths to add the base module as a dependency to the ui-projects.

```json
...
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "base": "file:../base"
   ...
}
...
```

So far so good...

In my CI environment (Jenkins) I use `npm ci` to install the dependencies. Since these steps are executed parallelly, the `node_modules` folder of base will be deleted by the `npm ci` call of `ui1` while `ui2` is trying to install the dependencies as well. This causes random errors of course...

Now my actual question: Is there a way to tell `npm ci` not to delete the `node_modules` of path dependencies? Of course any other hint to solve this kind of problem is appreciated as well... ;)

Thanks a lot for your help!